# How to schedule transaction replication in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, schedule, transactional-replication

I wanted to schedule the transaction replication. How do I do it?
Currently I have set up a transaction replication which runs continuously and synchronizes the changes with immediate effect.

I need to configure a replication which will gather logs from the publication once in a day.

Is there any possibility?

Comment: you can schedule replication jobs on subscriber for pull and publisher for push https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms151702%28v=sql.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Check out [CDC](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522489(v=sql.105).aspx)(Change Data Capture).